# What is different between 分かります and　分かりました。

Tags: meaning

What is different between 分かります and　分かりました。

Comment: Do you know how to express present and past tense in Japanese?

Comment: @Earthling But this is not a tense question.

Comment: I think that tense is relevant, but it interacts with aspect in a way that may be non-obvious.

Comment: I think also that it is tense-relevant : think that わかります is along the lines of "I am understanding/I know" meaning a continuous action, whereas 分かりました is along "I understood",　meaning something that has been learned (and is done). But well, the answer's good.

Answer (score 13):

A very good question.

Despite how it might look on the surface, this is definitely ***not*** a question about tense.

We use the two phrases differently depending on the situations -- more specifically, on the content of the discourse.  In other words, it depends on what the ***other*** person has just said to you.

> You use 「わかりました」 when you understand the explanation or instruction that the other person has just given to you.  ***It is an expression of comprehension of and obedience to what has been explained to you.***  You just learned something ***now***.

Guy: "To get to the XXX Park, you go ~~~~~."

You: 「わかりました。ありがとうございます。」　You will never say 「わかります」 here.

> 「わかります」 is quite different in that it is used to say "Yes, I know." or "I know what you mean."  ***It is an expression of knowledge and sometimes, sympathy.***

Guy: 「『懐疑的』の意味はわかりますか。」"Do you know what 懐疑的 means?"

You: 「はい、わかります。」

or --

Woman: "My husband just sits in the couch and watches TV ~~~~~.  He never helps me with ~~~~."

You:「わかります。My husband is the same way.」

Comment: Excellent ! I would simply add that in english terms, usage of 分かりました is similar to that of "understood" maybe more casual whereas 分かります can be used as "I understand/I feel you" but I know it's not always a good idea to provide translations...

Answer (score 0):

分かりました　=　i understood 
分かります　=　i understand