# Can you use わかる instead of わかりました?

Tags: grammar, phrases

If your teacher or your leader orders you to do sth or tells you sth, I always hear people say 'はい、わかりました。' But I also once heard somebody say 'わかる' instead of 'わかりました' to reply. Can people do that? Can I use both of them?

Answer (score 3):

わかる (present form) is never used when you accept an order/request from anyone. It's used when referring to something you already know. Its politer equivalent is わかります. They are often used to show your sympathy.

> - わかる。: I know. I understand that. You can say that. Yeah it really is.
> - わかります。: (polite version of わかる) Yes. I know. I understand that. I agree.

わかった is the phrase you have to use when you accept someone's request. Its politer equivalent is わかりました.

> - わかった。 Okay. Got it. I see. Understood.
> - わかりました。: (polite version of わかった) Okay. I see. Understood. Yes sir.

See: [What is different between 分かります and　分かりました。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21270/5010)

You should almost always use the politer versions to your boss. You may occasionally see someone excitedly say わかる! to their boss at an izakaya restaurant, though.

Comment: Could you please explain that in the respect of japanese 時制 and 相, 完了and 未完了?

Comment: @Null I'm not very good at tense/aspect... Somehow I feel this わかった is simple 過去, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: thank you, but when talking about tense I feel that it would be complex to understand the usage, I fell that わかった is more like 完了相 rather than 過去, like somebody already know the request or order.

Answer (score 1):

So broadly and almost overall saying, you can not or should I say, you'd better refrain from using.

"わかりました" is, as you can see, is including 丁寧語｛ていねいご｝ ます、です、（ which is conjugated ) so that I think almost nobody would say "わかる", especially to your **leader**. If your teacher or leader is almost equal to your very close friend, then "わかる" would be possible. I think somebody who is so intimate with the teacher/leader would have said so.